# Why is my Rails API integration test failing for a create action due to a missing id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, integration-testing

I'm stumped with a rails API problem testing problem, I'm hoping someone can help.

I am creating a rails API back end, and created a scaffold for "Employees" with four fields, namely: first_name, last_name, phone, email. The challenge I am having is my Create test is failing, with the following error:

`Minitest::UnexpectedError: ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"api/v1/employees"}, missing required keys: [:id]`

However, I can't for the life of me figure out why (I have googled, and search stack overflow and can't find anyone with a solution to this).

**Dev server**

Using Httpie i tested the post method in dev, and it appears to work correctly, see below:

When I run `http POST localhost:3000/api/v1/employees first_name=Edward last_name=Peters phone=0231231231 email=123@test.com`

I receive the following response:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
ETag: W/"55f26b9df2c29403bab760101fe31475"
Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none
X-Request-Id: 8d9e2dd1-7fdc-4379-be2b-3b060270bac2
X-Runtime: 0.059854
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

{
    "created_at": "2019-10-30T21:42:43.083Z",
    "email": "123@test.com",
    "first_name": "Edward",
    "id": 52,
    "last_name": "Peters",
    "phone": "0231231231",
    "updated_at": "2019-10-30T21:42:43.083Z"
}
```

Based on this the controller action appears to be working correctly, however, the test fails. My Controller and test are as follows:

**api/v1/employees_controller.rb**

```
module Api
  module V1
    class EmployeesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_employee, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

    # GET /employees
    def index
      @employees = Employee.all

      render json: @employees
    end

    # GET /employees/1
    def show
      render json: @employee
    end

    **# POST /employees
    def create
      @employee = Employee.new(employee_params)
      if @employee.save
        render json: @employee, status: :created
      else
        render json: @employee.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
    end**

    # PATCH/PUT /employees/1
    def update
      if @employee.update(employee_params)
        render json: @employee
      else
        render json: @employee.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
    end

    # DELETE /employees/1
    def destroy
      @employee.destroy
    end

    private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_employee
      @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def employee_params
      params.require(:employee).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :phone, :email)
    end
  end
  end
end
```

**employees_controller_test.rb**

```
require 'test_helper'

class EmployeesControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup do
    @employee = employees(:one)
    @update_employee = employees(:two)
  end

  test "should get index" do
    get api_v1_employees_url, as: :json
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should create employee" do
    assert_difference('Employee.count' ) do
      print "Employee id: #{Employee.last.id}"
      post api_v1_employee_url, params: { employee: {
                                            email: @employee.email,
                                            first_name: @employee.first_name,
                                            last_name: @employee.last_name,
                                            phone: @employee.phone }
                                          }, as: :json
      print "Employee id: #{Employee.last.id}"
    end

    follow_redirect!
    assert_response 201
  end

  test "should show employee" do
    get api_v1_employee_url(@employee), as: :json
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should update employee" do
    patch api_v1_employee_url(@employee), params: { employee: {
                                                    email: @update_employee.email,
                                                    first_name: @update_employee.first_name,
                                                    last_name: @update_employee.last_name,
                                                    phone: @update_employee.phone }
                                                  }, as: :json
    assert_response 200
  end

  test "should destroy employee" do
    assert_difference('Employee.count', -1) do
      delete api_v1_employee_url(@employee), as: :json
    end

    assert_response 204
  end
end
```

Working through the error that I mentioned above, it appears that the test is failing when the method tries to return the json response for the new record. However, looking at the method itself, it appears that it should retrieve this when the `@employee` variable is saved.

Thanks so much for any guidance!

Comment: Don't you want to post to `api_v1_employees_url` instead of `api_v1_employee_url`? `api_v1_employee_url` expects an `:id` since it's for an `Employee`.

Comment: Oh man, I feel so dense for missing that :/ That fixed it, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jvillian for the insight - I was trying to post to the `api_v1_employee_url` which expects an `id` parameter, rather than the `api_v1_employees_url` in the test.